# Wordpress Ubuntu 14.04 ssh2 error: Failed to connect to SSH2 Server 127.0.0.1:22

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, apache2, libssh2

I am trying to set up Wordpress locally on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I have followed these steps provided by digitalocean:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04

After that I want to be able to make any updates and install themes and plugins. Once I chose to install something new, I get to the page that requests Hostname, user, password and the methods FTP, FTPS(SSL) and SSH2. As I didn't know what to do next, I followed this:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu

I managed to do all the steps without a problem, until the time of testing the changes. On the wordpress installation page, I select:

```
    hostame: 127.0.0.1
    username: wp-user
    password: (I leave this blank)
    public key: /home/wp-user/wp_rsa.pub
    private key: /home/wp-user/wp_rsa
    -and the radio button, set to SSH2.
```

Once I click proceed, I get: "Failed to connect to SSH2 Server 127.0.0.1:22".
Could you please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your time,
Orestes.

Comment: You should definitly not choose an empty password for SSH. That might enable the world to do with your computer whatever it wants.

Comment: I don't want to set up a public server. My aim is to set up wordpress just so I can experiment with it locally. I don't think that anyone can connect to my server, as I have no static IP. I keep your advice in mind, but that is not my problem here! Plus as it is clearly a new field for me, I wanted to follow the exact steps the tutorial provided, in order to find as less problems as I could.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I hadn't set up the server correctly. I was missing the "openssh-server" package.
`apt-get install openssh-server`

solved the case. Just in case you are having a difficulty with connecting to your localhost or a server, be sure to:

```
which ssh
which sshd
```

If they both return the location where they are located, then you can go on looking up somewhere else for the problem.